# Testng how to get all the log steps in aftermethod for post issue on some bug tracking tools

Tags: selenium, log4j, testng

I am working on a project where if test case is failed I have to post a bug on their bug tracking tools through the tools. But they want in a bug report all the steps should mentioned properly with error.

Like in the description they want like this

1. Open Url
2. List item
3. Click the submit button Dashboard title is not match properly
   In My automation code, I have written log

```
public class logtest {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void Before(){
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        Log.info("Open URl");
        //Opened url
        Log.info("Click on the submit button");
        // Submit button Clicked
        Log.info("Open Dashboard");
        Log.info("Dashboard Title match");
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void AfterMethod(ITestResult result){
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            PostIssue_to_Somewhere();
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Is there any want I can get all the steps that I print inside `@Test` in the after method
so I can post bugs to their board through API

I think I can save the result somewhere and print it the end of the test case but I don't think it's an ideal solution. If you have any suggestion or way that I can manage it using testing that will really helpful

Comment: Show us how you define `Log` and how you import the class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the result in after test method. you should use TestNG listener for get the results

**Steps to get them :**

1. First create your own class with extend listener class

> ```
> public class Listener implements ITestListener
> ```

2. Then use the override method to get the results

   @Override
   public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {

   }

there are several method to get the exact data,

1. OnStart- OnStart method is called when any Test starts.
2. onTestSuccess- onTestSuccess method is called on the success of any test
3. onTestFailure- onTestFailure method is called on the failureof any Test.
4. onTestSkipped- onTestSkipped method is called on
   skipped of any Test
5. onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage- method
   is called each time Test fails but is within success percentage.
6. onFinish- onFinish method is called after all Tests are executed.

Comment: I already have this implementation, I just need to all the steps at the end in iTestResult

Answer (score 0):

Use Extent Report and then use its method like (log, pass, fail ) to log your steps in your report, based on your test result, if you still need help let me know :)
You can see the full project demo code at ( below is code for the extent report) https://github.com/0kakarot0/ExtentReportBasic.git

```
public class MyExtentReport {
private WebDriver driver;
ExtentSparkReporter spark;
ExtentReports extentReports;
ExtentTest extentTest;

public MyExtentReport(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;

}

//Created Extent Report Html File
public void extentReporter() {
    Date date = new Date();
    String rightNow = "Spark"+ date.getTime() + ".html" ;
    String pathOfFile = "allReports/"+rightNow;
    spark = new ExtentSparkReporter(pathOfFile);

    extentReports = new ExtentReports();
    extentReports.attachReporter(spark);
}

public void logTestNameAndDescription(String name, String description){
    extentTest = extentReports.createTest(name, description);
}

public void logTestInfo(String testInfo){
    extentTest.log(Status.INFO,testInfo);
}

public void logPassedTestSteps(String logPassMessage){
    extentTest.pass(logPassMessage);
}
public void logFailTestSteps(String logFailMessage){
    extentTest.fail(logFailMessage);
}
public void logFailTestScreenShot(String reasonOfFailure){
    extentTest.fail(reasonOfFailure,MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("utils/failedTestScreenShot/screenshot.png").build());
}

public void flushExtentReport(){
    extentReports.flush();
}
```